# The construction of push-forward in algebraic equivarient K-theory

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

What is the construction of push-forward in algebraic equivarient K-theory ?

Comment: It is what I expect but I have problems in verifying that it is a correct construction. 


Comment: Do you mean why is it well-defined?  If so, it's also the same reason as in ordinary K-theory, just use the long exact sequence.  (Hopefully that helps, but if not, maybe you could be more specific about the point of confusion?)

Answer (score 6):

It's the same as in non-equivariant $K$-theory.  For a $G$-equivariant proper morphism $f:X \to Y$ and an equivariant coherent sheaf $F$ on $X$, define $$f^G_*[F] = \sum (-1)^i [R^i f_*F],$$ which makes sense because each higher direct image is equivariant (and coherent, because $f$ is proper).

An interesting situation is when $Y$ is a point, in which case this is the "equivariant Euler characteristic," an alternating sum of (virtual) $G$-representations.

Comment: Thank you a lot! The deal is that  I have made a reduction of my problem to the question in equivarient K-theory but I am not familiar with it and I cant find an article with basic definitions

Comment: Sure.  One place to go for basic definitions is the Chapter 5 of the book by Chriss and Ginzburg.  (Unfortunately there's no index, but that chapter is pretty easy to navigate.)

Comment: The article of Merkurjev in the Handbook of K-theory is also quite useful: it summarizes basic useful properties.